# which is better to store data in session in PHP ? array or json

Tags: php, arrays, json, session

I'm building a shopping cart,and have to store the product list that user has chosen before in SESSION.
 I wonder which kind of data is better in this situation ?

1. Storing in JSON: by this way, I have to json_encode and json_decode each the set and get.
2. Storing in array.

My question is :

- Thinking about performance, which is better ?

Comment: Given that one way needs you to encode/decode yourself and the other doesn't - isn't it obvious?

Comment: Array of course. As you mentioned, if you store it in json, you have to encode and decode each time. That hits the performance (although only very slightly to be un-noticable).

Comment: of course array. you can use array as @fijas says

Comment: To store data in session with array format is better.

Comment: Sorry for noise created by my answer. I am still sleepy and misread question. I was sure, you were storing data in db from session. For sessions, use array, of course. Anyway, what I've written about db architecture is still correct, not wrong, reason of downvote was being off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Store the session data as an array. The $_SESSION superglobal is an array anyway so you'll be working with it natively. Not sure why you'd want to use JSON at all for something like this.

However, the third option that Leri mentioned is also a good idea. In the context of an e-commerce system, this will allow you to do better things in the future with the data - you can track uncompleted orders and make contextual recommendations etc.

Comment: Thanks ! I've read source code of a shopping cart extension which is written in PHP, they store shopping cart info in SESSION using JSON, so I just wonder why they had to encode to json and save in SESSION like that ?

Comment: @Chung Which e-commerce app do you use?

Comment: @Leri I read Yii shop extension for Yii framework https://github.com/thyseus/yii-shop